# Error al hacer un Select en Mysql desde C#

Tags: c#, mysql

```
public string Usuario
{
    get { return usuario; }
    set { usuario = value; }
}
public string Clave
{
    get { return clave; }
    set { clave = value; }
}

public string Tipo
{
    get { return tipo; }
    set { tipo = value; }
}

MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lgn WHERE CARGO='" + tipo + "'and USUARIO='" + usuario + "'and PASS='" + clave, CONEXION.ObtenerConexion());
```

El error que me aparece es el siguiente:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near ''6Ol/iZcnHemlteHtFuoxsA==' at line 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te falta cerrar el `'` después del password:

```
MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lgn WHERE CARGO='" + tipo + "'and USUARIO='" + usuario + "'and PASS='" + clave + "'", CONEXION.ObtenerConexion());
```

Pero fuera de esto **tienes un grave problema de [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)** que es una vulnerabilidad que podría permitir que se ejecuten consultas y comandos que no hayas previsto, pudiendo en el peor de los casos dar acceso total a tu base de datos.

En lugar de concatenar las variables crea una **consulta parametrizada**:

```
var comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lgn WHERE CARGO = @cargo and USUARIO = @usuario and PASS = @pass");
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cargo", tipo);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", usuario);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", clave);
```

Comment: Carlos gracias por tu ayuda, pero vs da un error y dice que parameter es solo de lectura

Comment: Julio, listo ya lo corregí

Comment: Carlos nuevamente gracias por tu ayuda pero al probar me sale la siguiente excepcion Connection must be valid and open.

Comment: Julio, ese es un error diferente, que no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta en cuestión. Lo que debes hacer es llamar al método `.Open()` del `MySqlConnection` antes de llamar tratar de leer los valores del `MySQLReader`

Comment: Si no te funciona puedes crear otra pregunta, pero esta vez colocando todo el código de la lectura de los datos

Answer (score 1):

Como dice el error, tienes un error de sintaxis, en tu ultima variable te falta cerrar la comilla simple `'`.

```
MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lgn WHERE CARGO='" + tipo + "'and USUARIO='" + usuario + "'and PASS='" + clave + "'", CONEXION.ObtenerConexion());
```

Comment: No solo le falta cerrar la ultima comilla sino que tambien debería separar **'and USUARIO** y dejarlo como **' and USUARIO**

Answer (score 1):

```
MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lgn WHERE CARGO='" + tipo + "'and USUARIO='" + usuario + "'and PASS='" + clave + "';", CONEXION.ObtenerConexion());
```

Falta la comilla en el campo clave.